# Why does adding a class to a p tag in the json of a seeder break that seeder?

Tags: laravel

I have a seeder that, in one part of it seeds a json column as shown below. If I have the text in a p tag everything seeds just fine.

This works:

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert(array(
  array(
    'json' => '<p>some text</p>'
  )
))
```

However if I add a class or a style tag to the text, it breaks the seeder! why? How? How do I get around this?

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert(array(
  array(
    'json' => '<p class="subtitle">some text</p>'
  )
))
```

The error that I get is `<<Unknown error>>: 3140 Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 27806 in value for column`

Comment: Check this [answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19981380/2815635)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```php
DB::table('table_name')->insert(array(
  array(
    'json' => json_encode('<p class="subtitle">some text</p>')
  )
))
```